# How to disable pasting to datepicker field in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there any way to disable pasting data to datepicker field in xamarin forms.

Thanks,
Renjith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found any proper solution for this, but got it working with a tweak. 
    I added a transparent boxview above picker and added a tapgesture to it. Now on tapping it i called the focus() of the picker. copy pasting is now blocked as we have the boxview above it.

Comment: I was looking for a non-hacky solution, but maybe this is the best we can do for now. Xamarin Forms has a loooong way to go before it grows up... :(

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no way to implement that because it is operacional system behavior

Answer (score 0):

Cut/paste functionality can be disabled natively in platform renderers. Here is an [extended answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52652596/2452764).

I've also posted the detailed solution in [this article](https://medium.com/@anna.domashych/xamarin-forms-disabling-cut-paste-menu-on-datepicker-e2dc96298a8f).