# I need to block the paste function in a datepicker on XamarinForms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

In the solution that I'm building, I have a date-picker that works fine. But, if the user press the touch and paste something, it will overwrite the date.

When the user pastes, the events of `OnElementChanged`, `OnElementPropertyChanged` and even the `INotifyPropertyChanged` are not raised. I also can't find a option to block the paste function. (When the date is choose normally, the events are being called.)

This happens in iOS and Android. Can someone help me? I am stuck and my researches don't help me much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**On iOS platform**

`DatePicker` behaves this way because under the hood it is implemented via `UITextField`.
To avoid editing of `UITextField` you have to assign it a delegate which returns `false` from `ShouldChangeCharacters` method.

The full solution will be the following:

Declare a child of a `DatePicker` in a shared project:

```
public class ExtendedDatePicker : DatePicker
{
}
```

Declare a corresponding renderer in iOS project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), typeof(ExtendedDatePickerRenderer))]  
...    

public class ExtendedDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer  
{  
    private UneditableUITextFieldDelegate _delegate = new UneditableUITextFieldDelegate();  

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)  
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.Delegate = _delegate;
    }
}
```

Implement the `UneditableUITextFieldDelegate`:

```
public class UneditableUITextFieldDelegate : NSObject, IUITextFieldDelegate
{
    [Export("textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:")]
    public bool ShouldChangeCharacters(UITextField textField, NSRange range, string replacementString) =>
        false;
}
```

This will not prevent the 'copy'/'paste' menu from being shown but `DatePicker` value will not be changed after pressing them.

**On Android platform**

The underlying UI element for `DatePicker` on Android is `EditText`.

I have posted articles explaining how to manipulate context menu of `EditText` in [native Android](https://medium.com/@anna.domashych/selectable-read-only-multiline-text-field-on-android-169c27c55408) and [Xamarin.Forms](https://medium.com/@anna.domashych/selectable-read-only-multiline-text-field-in-xamarin-forms-69d09276d580). You can get the overall idea there.

I was not able to perform a long tap on a `DatePicker` to see the problem thus I can only guess about the proper fix, but a renderer similar to this one should completely disable context menu for selected text as well as a paste option when a user taps a cursor:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), typeof(ExtendedDatePickerRenderer))]
...

public class ExtendedDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
{
    public ExtendedDatePickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.CustomSelectionActionModeCallback = new CustomSelectionActionModeCallback();
        Control.CustomInsertionActionModeCallback = new CustomInsertionActionModeCallback();
    }
}
```

`CustomInsertionActionModeCallback` and `CustomInsertionActionModeCallback` would return `false` from `OnCreateActionMode` and will prevent menu from appearing.

```
public class CustomInsertionActionModeCallback : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
{
    public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu) => false;

    public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode m, IMenuItem i) => false;

    public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu) => true;

    public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) { }
}

public class CustomSelectionActionModeCallback : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
{
    public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode m, IMenuItem i) => false;

    public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu) => false;

    public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu) => true;

    public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) { }
}
```

**=======**
**UPDATE:** this question inspired me to create an [article](https://medium.com/@anna.domashych/xamarin-forms-disabling-cut-paste-menu-on-datepicker-e2dc96298a8f) extending this answer with some explanations and details.

Comment: if you find the solution for android and you can share it I will be very grateful

Comment: @ViníciusBritto I've updated my answer with some information for Android platform. From my experience, both short and long tap on `DatePicker` would open a standard system dialog, so I was not able to 100% test my solution. I hope it would work for you, otherwise please leave a comment.

Comment: Works to android as well! Thank you so much!!

Comment: The CustomSelectionActionModeCallback is not working for Tablet. I believe that in the old versions of android the `CustomSelectionActionModeCallback` will not work. Any variation that i can use?

Comment: In my opinion, it's rather OS version or device manufacturer issue than the device form factor